# Expected value of number of factors of number?

Tags: probability, expected-value

How can I find the E(x) of a number of factors of a number?
Each number can take down into primary factors. For example: the factors numbers of 42 is 2,7,3 So the quantity is 3.

What is the E(x) for 1 until 50?
Prob(The probability that the number k will divide the number) = 50/k
Random variable = k

so I think it is:

sigma (1 to 50) 50/k * k = 2500?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about the typical number of prime factors that an integer of a given size will have. In that case, you'll be interested to read about the [Hardy–Ramanujan theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy–Ramanujan_theorem).

Comment: @GregMartin I don't think you're right. I'm learning a probability course and It does not make sense to me "Hardy Ramanujan theorem". It should be related to the expectation formula.

Comment: I think there is nothing better than to determine simply the number of prime factors (I guess multiplicity is not considered) for all the numbers upto $50$ and use those to calculate $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$. Fortunately, the number of prime factors cannot exceed $3$ because of $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7=210>50$ and $3$ prime factors occurs only twice in the given range. Also note that the number of prime factors is $0$ for $n=1$

Comment: @Peter I was told in the exercise that it is forbidden to calculate the number of primary factors per number. I was thinking of doing something like this: the approximate probability that a number is divisible by a prime number - p is 1 / p so you can just calculate the amount 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + ... +1/47
The problem is that it's an approximation. And asked me for an exact answer.

Comment: For the exact answer, you can modify your formula to $\frac1{50}\lfloor\frac{50}2\rfloor + \frac1{50}\lfloor\frac{50}3\rfloor + \frac1{50}\lfloor\frac{50}5\rfloor + \cdots + \frac1{50}\lfloor\frac{50}{47}\rfloor$.

Comment: @GregMartin I do not know if this is the way they asked but it seems that is indeed the answer, if someone has another way it is better.